# Não consigo fazer upload de dois arquivos para o mesmo documento em uma relação ManyToOne

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

Olá, galera! Boa noite.
Então, eu tenho uma entidade chamada arquivos e outra entidade chamada documento.
Um documento pode ter vários arquivos.
Eu fiz um módulo de upload dos arquivos.

O problema que tô enfrentando é q quando eu faço o upload de mais de um arquivo para o mesmo documento eu tenho um retorno 'not found'. Estou aqui sem saber p onde ir. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

MINHA ENTIDADE ARQUIVO

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Arquivo {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private long id;
    
    private @ManyToOne Documento documento;
    
    private String tipoArquivo;
    
    private @Lob byte[] data;
    
    public Arquivo() {}
    
    public Arquivo(Documento documento, String tipoArquivo, byte[] data) {
        this.documento = documento;
        this.tipoArquivo = tipoArquivo;
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

MINHA ENTIDADE DOCUMENTO

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Documento {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private @ManyToOne Morador morador;

    @NotNull
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private LocalDate dataEntrega;
    
    private @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) TipoDocumento tipoDocumento;

}
```

MEU CONTROLLER DE ARQUIVO COM O MÉTODO DO UPLOAD

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Upload de uma imagem", notes = "Upload de uma nova imagem.")
    @Transactional
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @PostMapping("/uploadArquivo")
    public Arquivo uploadArquivo(
            @ApiParam(name = "arquivo", value = "Arquivo que irá ser feito o upload.", required = true)
            @RequestParam("arquivo") MultipartFile arquivo, 
            @ApiParam(name = "documento_id", value = "id do documento.", required = true, type = "long")
            @RequestParam("documento_id") long id) {

        Documento documento = docRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NegocioException("Documento não encontrado."));

            Arquivo arq = null;
            
            try {
                arq = new Arquivo(documento, arquivo.getContentType(), arquivo.getBytes());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new FileStorageException("Não foi possível criar o arquivo. Por favor, tente novamente.", e);
            }

            return repository.save(arq);
        }
```

O RETORNO QUE TENHO É ESSE

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-07-29T02:35:19.853+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/UploadArquivo"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa mensagem de erro em específico não é relacionada ao código ou lógica da sua aplicação. A mensagem "not found" é relacionada ao "path" da sua API. Você não está chamando a API certa. Você está chamando "UploadArquivo", sendo que a API é "uploadArquivo"

Comment: Putz, mano. Me passei geral kkkkk. Valeu aí!!